# Stack and Queue arrays returning wrong values

Tags: java

I've created stack and queue arrays which hold integers and have a max capacity of ten. I added the values 1-11 and then will remove and print each value until empty. The queue is not only printing 11 values, but also printing 1 instead of 11 for the first value. The stack however is only printing and removing the 10 values but is giving me an IndexOutBoundsException that is not being caught. Any idea why?

Output:

```
run:
Print queue: 
11 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
Print stack: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
  at lab4.Stack.pop(Stack.java:44)
  at lab4.Lab4.main(Lab4.java:54)
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Main:

```
    Queue queue = new Queue(10);
    Stack stack = new Stack(10);

    queue.insert(1);
    queue.insert(2);
    queue.insert(3);
    queue.insert(4);
    queue.insert(5);
    queue.insert(6);
    queue.insert(7);
    queue.insert(8);
    queue.insert(9);
    queue.insert(10);
    queue.insert(11);

    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(3);
    stack.push(4);
    stack.push(5);
    stack.push(6);
    stack.push(7);
    stack.push(8);
    stack.push(9);
    stack.push(10);
    stack.push(11);

    System.out.println("Print queue: ");
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        long n = queue.remove();
        System.out.print(n + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Print stack: ");
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        Object value = stack.pop();
        System.out.print(value + " ");
    }
```

Stack.java

```
public class Stack {

private int[] stackArray;   // Stack array of objects
private int maxSize = 10;       // Max size of the stack
private int top;                    // top integer of stack

public Stack(int maxSize) {
    stackArray = new int[maxSize];
    top = -1;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (top == maxSize); // true if stack is empty
}

public boolean isFull() {
    return (top == maxSize - 1); // true if full
}

public int size() {
    return (top + 1); // Return the # of items
}

public void push(int item) // put element into array
{
    if (!isFull()) {
        top++;
        stackArray[top] = item;
    }

}

public Object pop() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        top--;
        return stackArray[top + 1];
    } else
        throw new IllegalStateException("Stack empty");
}

public Object peek() {
    return stackArray[top];
}

public String toString() {
    return "Size: " + maxSize + " Capcaity: " + top; // complete: show the size and capacity
}
```

}

Queue.java

```
public class Queue {

private int maxSize = 10;
private int[] queueArray;
private int front;
private int rear;
private int nItems;

// Constructor
public Queue(int s) {
    queueArray = new int[maxSize];
    front = 0;
    rear = -1;
    nItems = 0;
}

// Insert item at rear of queue
public void insert(int j) {
    if (rear == maxSize - 1) {  // Deal with wraparound
        rear = -1;
    }
    queueArray[++rear] = j;
    nItems++;
}

public int remove() {
    int temp = queueArray[front++];
    if (front == maxSize) {
        front = 0;
    }
    nItems--;
    return temp;
}

public int peekFront() {
    return queueArray[front];
}

public int peekRear() {
    return queueArray[front];
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (nItems == 0);
}

public boolean isFull() {
    return (nItems == maxSize);
}

public int size() {
    return nItems;
}
```

}

Comment: Try to debug a simple failing example.

Comment: Just a general FYI, naming your classes after things that already exist in core Java is generally a bad idea (there already exists a Queue interface and Stack class).

Comment: 1-11 is 11 items, your max size is 10.

Comment: Looks like `Stack.isEmpty()` is off by one.  When it is full, `top = 9`.

Comment: Yeah you're right. isEmpty() method should be top == maxSize + 1. However, I'm still getting the out of bounds exception

Comment: when you push, you need to increment 'top' after you done pushing. Otherwise you  wasting the first element in the array. same in pop.

Answer (score 0):

These are pretty simple fixes! For the queue, you need to set your maxSize to 11. This will allow you to print each number in the queue correctly without printing the 11 in front. Long story short, given you have 11 total elements in your queue, a max queue size of 11 is necessary.

```
public class Queue {

private int maxSize = 11;
private int[] queueArray;
private int front;
private int rear;
private int nItems;
}
```

Now, in terms of your stack, this was also a pretty simple fix. As of right now, your code is returning top == maxSize (or 10) when the stack is empty. This is causing an issue with the pop function. However, when the stack is empty,  top should equal -1. So make sure to set top == -1 in the isEmpty() function. You should also change int maxSize = 10 to int maxSize= 11 and make the necessary change in the pop() function as well as this is where the error is occurring. Finally, make sure to change the value in your stack initialization from 10 to 11. I've changed your code and it should now work properly! Enjoy!

```
public class Stack {

private int[] stackArray;   // Stack array of objects
private int maxSize = 11;       // Max size of the stack
private int top;                    // top integer of stack

public Stack(int maxSize) {
    stackArray = new int[maxSize];
    top = -1;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (top == -1); // true if stack is empty
}

public boolean isFull() {
    return (top == maxSize); // true if full
}

public int size() {
    return (top-1); // Return the # of items
}

public void push(int item) // put element into array
{
    if (!isFull()) {
        top++;
        stackArray[top] = item;
    }

}
public Object pop() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        return stackArray[top--];
    } else
        throw new IllegalStateException("Stack empty");
}

public Object peek() {
    return stackArray[top+1];
}

public String toString() {
    return "Size: " + maxSize + " Capcaity: " + top; // complete: show the size and capacity
}
```